# httr2 - API request error: OpenSSL SSL_read: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading, errno 0

Tags: r, httr2

I'm trying to request data from an API but getting an error. Here's the full code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

req <- request("https://www.ec.europa.eu/agrifood/api/beef/prices?memberStateCodes=PT&years=2019,2020&months=1,3,9&weeks=5,6,7,8,40,41,42&beginDate=01/09/2019&endDate=02/02/2020&carcassCategories=heifers,cows")

resp <- req |> req_perform()
```

And the full response error:
Error in `req_perform()`:
! Failed to perform HTTP request.
Caused by error in `curl::curl_fetch_memory()`:
! OpenSSL SSL_read: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading, errno 0

Can anyone suggest a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"https://ec.europa.eu/agrifood/api/beef/prices?memberStateCodes=PT&years=2019,2020&months=1,3,9&weeks=5,6,7,8,40,41,42&beginDate=01/09/2019&endDate=02/02/2020&carcassCategories=heifers,cows" %>% 
  jsonlite::fromJSON()

  memberStateCode memberStateName  beginDate    endDate weekNumber   price    unit    category productCode
1              PT        Portugal 27/01/2020 02/02/2020          5 €352.20 €/100Kg     Heifers        E O4
2              PT        Portugal 27/01/2020 02/02/2020          5 €388.70 €/100Kg Young bulls        A U2
3              PT        Portugal 27/01/2020 02/02/2020          5 €386.60 €/100Kg Young bulls        A U3
4              PT        Portugal 27/01/2020 02/02/2020          5 €216.20 €/100Kg        Cows        D O3
5              PT        Portugal 27/01/2020 02/02/2020          5 €425.00 €/100Kg      Steers        C O4
6              PT        Portugal 27/01/2020 02/02/2020          5 €369.90 €/100Kg Young bulls        A R2
```

Comment: Hahahha, it works! Maybe I got too obsessed with the httr/httr2 packages and overlooked my real goal. Thanks anyway!